# Why am i still unauthorized? HTTP Twitch 2AuthO request in Lua with coro-http

Tags: lua, luvit

I am 100% sure that my client-id and client-secret are valid. I used it in my python code and it just worked fine

```
local http = require("coro-http")
local json = require("json")

local url = "https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token"

local client_id = "<>"
local client_secret = "<>"

local headers = {
["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

local body = "client_id=" .. client_id .. "&client_secret=" .. client_secret .. "&grant_type=client_credentials"

local response, w = http.request("POST", url, headers, body)
print(w)

local data = json.decode(w)
local access_token = data.access_token

local headers = {
["Client-ID"] = client_id,
["Authorization"] = "Bearer " .. access_token 
}

local response, b = http.request("GET", "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channels?broadcaster_id=141981764", headers)
  print(b)
```

Getting token and then do a simple get request

Comment: `"client_id=" .. client_id .. "&client_secret=" .. client_secret .. "&grant_type=client_credentials"` - properly `urlencode` your parameters; perhaps they don't change if `urlencode`d, but you shouldn't rely on this. Also, are you sure that the `body` line shouldn't be part of the `url`?

Comment: Please also provide your Python script for comparison; the differences may allow telling where the bug in your Lua script lies.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this repository](https://github.com/DigitalPulseSoftware/NotaBot/blob/master/twitchapi.lua#L58) which is doing exactly what you're trying to.

From the code you provided and the one from the above repo, I would say @LMD comment is the way to go. You need to urlencode your body string.
Maybe [querystring from luvit](https://luvit.io/api/querystring.html) could be a good starting point.